# Why is ddply not working on this data frame?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame as follows:

```
plan     address                                                                 preferred
S3440    5301 E Huron River Dr Rm 1538 Ann Arbor, MI 48106 1-734-712-2492, xxx   Not applicable
S3440    2140 E Ellsworth Rd Ann Arbor, MI 48108 1-734-477-9006, xxx             Not applicable
S3440    2215 Fuller Road Ann Arbor, MI 48105 1-734-761-7933, xxx                Not applicable
```

and such.  About 27000s rows worth.  There is more after the phone number after the address tab, I just omitted it for brevity.

I want to split the address up, basically removing the phone number and everything after it. I've been able to do that through a regular expression:

```
 str_split(x,'( [0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})')
```

I want to apply this function on every single row, so I've written a ddply "function:"

```
ddply(final_data2, .(address), function(x){str_split(x,'( [0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})')})
```

However, this spits out the error:

```
Error: String must be an atomic vector
```

and I don't know why.  Can someone help me fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is `class(final_data2$address)`? I'm going to guess it's a "factor" and not a "character". Try converting to character with `as.character`

Comment: Interesting, I can easily walk to at least one of those addresses.

Comment: In your `ddply` call, then function will get (still) get a data frame, so your `str_split()` should use `x$address`. Therefore, from another angle, you could just as well do (not tested): `str_split(final_data2$address, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the pattern showed, you could try: (without using `ddply`)

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(final_data2$address, perl('.*(?= .-.*)'))
 #[1] "5301 E Huron River Dr Rm 1538 Ann Arbor, MI 48106"
 #[2] "2140 E Ellsworth Rd Ann Arbor, MI 48108"          
 #[3] "2215 Fuller Road Ann Arbor, MI 48105"
```

#### Explanation

```
 ('.*(?= .-.*) # extract everything before a `space`, followed by one character, followed by `-`.
```

Using your code:

```
 simplify2array(str_split(final_data2$address, '( [0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})'))[c(T,F)]

#[1] "5301 E Huron River Dr Rm 1538 Ann Arbor, MI 48106"
#[2] "2140 E Ellsworth Rd Ann Arbor, MI 48108"          
#[3] "2215 Fuller Road Ann Arbor, MI 48105"
```

I don't understand why you want to use `ddply` and use `address` as grouping variable.  This seems to work, but it is not needed.

```
unlist(daply(final_data2, .(address), function(x){str_split(x$address,'( [0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})')}),use.names=F)[c(T,F)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An apply works

```
apply(final_data2[,2],1,function(x) str_split(x,'[0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}')[[1]][1])
```

But a gsub is faster

```
gsub("[0-9]-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}.*","",final_data2$address)
```